# Oracle BigData error while accessing data on Hue

Tags: hive, hue

I have Oracle Big Data. I have created a table in HIVE. I am able to view the data through HUE in HIVE. But when I am trying to browse to that file I am getting error related HDFS Super User.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that WebHdfs is [configured properly](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh_hue_configure.html#topic_15_4_1_unique_1).